# Python. Acceder a la primera fila de un Treeview. Primero para leer los datos y posteriormente para borrarla

Tags: python

Estoy iniciandome en Python, me gusta mucho y me he animado a dar mis primeros pasos con un programa sencillo, pero evidentemente me surgen problemas.

Quiero acceder a la primera fila de un Treeview.
Primero para leer los valores de algunas columnas y luego para borrar esa fila.

Inicialmente creí haberlo conseguido usando este código:

```
            variable = tabla1.item("I001")["values"][0]
```

Tomaba los valores y luego para borrarla, hacía algo parecido:

```
            tabla1.delete('I001')
```

Luego actualicé el Treeview, convencido que de nuevo el primer item sería "I001", pero resulta que no, que el primer item era diferente y ya no sirve ese código.

En este foro he encontrado esta solución para seleccionar la primera fila. Las tres primeras líneas localizan la primera fila y ponen el foco. Luego yo he añadido las dos últimas filas para borrar la fila seleccionada.
Lamentablemente no ha funcionado:

```
            item = tabla1.index(0)
            tabla1.selection_set(item)
            tabla1.focus(item)
            x = tabla1.selection()[0]
            tabla1.delete(x)
```

Me sale este error en la primera línea:

```
            _tkinter.TclError: Item 0 not found
```

Seguro que debe existir una forma sencilla para acceder a esa primera fila de un Treeview, ya que entiendo que debe ser algo muy habitual, pero no consigo encontrar cómo.

La respuesta de @abulafia sugiriendo utilizar `tabla.identify_row(0)` me pareció perfecta, pero al probarla vi que no funcionaba dentro de la función y sí fuera de ella. Intuyo que habré cometido un fallo en el código. Lo incluyo y a ver si me ayudais a descifrar el enigma.

En la línea 63 justo después de crear el Treeview, aplico "identify" y me da el resultado del Id. Hago lo mismo dentro de la función "delete" y me da el error:
"Cannot delete root item"

Este es el código donde se puede apreciar mi problema:

```
    import tkinter.font as tkFont
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, messagebox
    import pandas as pd
    
    class Prueba:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.title("  - Prueba de Treeview -")
            self.root.state('zoomed')
            fuente2 = tkFont.Font(family="Arial", size=12, weight="bold")
    
            # Crear Frames
            frame_01 = Frame(self.root, bd=1, bg="white")
            frame_01.place(width=600, height=250, x=100, y=200)
    
            # Crear Treeview
            tabla1 = ttk.Treeview(frame_01, height=20, selectmode="browse")
    
            kk = [[{'count': 6, 'item_id': 11313},
                   {'count': 6, 'item_id': 11348},
                   {'count': 1, 'item_id': 11338}],
                  [{'count': 4, 'item_id': 11311},
                   {'count': 3, 'item_id': 11281}]]
    
            resultado = {'user_id': [], 'count': [], 'item_id': []}
            for i, lista in enumerate(kk):
                for d in lista:
                    resultado['user_id'].append(i)
                    resultado['count'].append(d['count'])
                    resultado['item_id'].append(d['item_id'])
    
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(resultado)
            # Clear old treeview
            tabla1.delete(*tabla1.get_children())
            # Set up new treeview
            tabla1["column"] = list(df1.columns)
            # Define las columnas
            tabla1.column(tabla1["column"][0], anchor=CENTER, width=100)
            tabla1.column(tabla1["column"][1], anchor=W, width=300)
            tabla1.column(tabla1["column"][2], anchor=W, width=300)
    
            # Define Headings
            tabla1.heading(tabla1["column"][0], anchor=CENTER)
            tabla1.heading(tabla1["column"][1], anchor=W)
            tabla1.heading(tabla1["column"][2], anchor=W)
    
            tabla1["show"] = "headings"
    
            # loop throught column list for headers
            for column in tabla1["column"]:
                tabla1.heading(column, text=column)
    
            # Put data in treeview
            df1_rows = df1.to_numpy().tolist()
    
            for row in df1_rows:
                tabla1.insert("", "end", values=row)
    
            # Pack the treeview finally
            tabla1.pack(side=TOP)
            x = tabla1.identify_row(0)
            print(x)
    
            def subir():
                rows = tabla1.selection()
                for row in rows:
                    tabla1.move(row, tabla1.parent(row), tabla1.index(row)-1)
    
            def bajar():
                x = tabla1.identify_row(0)
                print(x)
                rows = tabla1.selection()
                for row in rows:
                    tabla1.move(row, tabla1.parent(row), tabla1.index(row)+1)
    
            def delete():
                deletel = messagebox.askokcancel("Eliminar", "¿Seguro que quieres eliminar la fila?")
                x = tabla1.identify_row(0)
                tabla1.delete(x)
    
            subirl = Button(self.root, text="Subir", font=fuente2, activebackground="white", command=subir)
            subirl.place(width=200, height=50, x=100, y=450)
            bajarl = Button(self.root, text="Bajar", font=fuente2, activebackground="white", command=bajar)
            bajarl.place(width=200, height=50, x=300, y=450)
            dell = Button(self.root, text="Eliminar", font=fuente2, activebackground="white", command=delete)
            dell.place(width=200, height=50, x=500, y=450)
    
        def run(self):
            self.root.mainloop()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Prueba().run()
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda!!

Comment: No tengo experiencia con treeviews, pero mirando su documentación parece que `tabla.identify_row(0)` te debería devolver el id del primer item en él. A partir de ahú ya puedes usar `tabla.item(id)` con el `id` que hubieras obtenido.

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia por tu rápida respuesta. Lo había probado y tampoco me funcionaba. Pero acabo de hacer una prueba y tu respuesta me ha abierto el camino. Ocurre lo siguiente:
El código 'tabla.identify_row(0)' lo he puesto dentro de un **def** y no me ha funcionado, no me da ninguna respuesta. Sin embargo si lo saco del **def** funciona perfectamente, me da el id de la primera fila (I001), que es lo que buscaba para poder seguir.
No sé  qué problema tengo para que no funcione dentro de la función. Voy a subir el código. Antes voy a limpiarlo. Lo subiré esta noche.
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `tabla1.get_children()[0]` para obtener el primer item. Asi siempre obtendrás el primer item del treeview sin importar cual sea su id.

Comment: Genial @DanteS ha sido la solución perfecta. Ya lo he probado y funciona perfectamente. Muchísimas gracias!!
Llevaba casi una semana dándole vueltas y consultando en la web. Tu respuesta ha dado en el clavo. 
Gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: Un placer Juan Carlos c: